# How to change a table direction in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am translating an English document into a right to left language. There is a table as follows:

[image]

I want a similar table in the target document and I'd like not to draw this manually again, but the problem with copying this is that it is left-to-right, as the small plus at the top-left corner shows. This consistent direction allows convenient tabbing between cells. But, for my target right-to-left language, this convenience is not obtained by simply copying the table as it does not allow tabbing between cells from right to left.
How can I change the direction of the table so that the top-left plus sign is shown at top-right corner of the table?

Comment: Try Right-click on the table and choose
Table Properties. In the Table tab, near the bottom, should be a setting for
RTL/LTR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the top-left plus, thus selecting the table. Now, right-click on the table and click Table Properties.
Under **Table direction**, select Right-to-left:
[image]

Click OK.

[image]

Now the direction is right-to-left and tabbing right-to-left between cells is possible.

Comment: That option seems to be gone in the current Office 365 Word.

Comment: Which edition are you using? I suspect there should be an option in the settings to enable right-to-left languages. I have not worked with MS Word for a long time though.